# how to group object array to multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];
        r[a.make].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

out put is like comes like this

```
{
"audi":[{"make":"audi","model":"r8","year":"2012"},{"make":"audi","model":"rs5","year":"2013"}],
"ford":[{"make":"ford","model":"mustang","year":"2012"},{"make":"ford","model":"fusion","year":"2015"}],
"kia":[{"make":"kia","model":"optima","year":"2012"}]}
```

But Expected Output is a multidimensional array

```
[  
[{"make":"audi","model":"r8","year":"2012"},{"make":"audi","model":"rs5","year":"2013"}],
[{"make":"ford","model":"mustang","year":"2012"},{"make":"ford","model":"fusion","year":"2015"}],[{"make":"kia","model":"optima","year":"2012"}]

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take only the values from the object with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    result = Object.values(cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];
        r[a.make].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this modified version with `Object.values()`

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];
        r[a.make].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    
const newResult = Object.values(result);

console.log(newResult);
```

Comment: This answer is equal to the answer provided by @NinaScholz

Comment: Yeah, we posted our answers at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
 const cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
        
const result = [...Object.values(cars).map(obj => obj)];
        
console.log(result);
```